# replace 0 with null in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, null

I want to replace 0's in mysql table with 'NULL'. I have read that querying the following way would replace 'NULL' with 0

```
SELECT COALESCE(null_column, 0) AS null_column FROM whatever;
```

But how to the other way?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use `NULLIF`, which will return `NULL` if the value in the first parameter matches the value in the second parameter.

```
SELECT NULLIF(null_column, 0) AS null_column FROM whatever
```

Answer (score 15):

```
update `whatever` set `null_column` = null where null_column = 0;
```

Comment: Not working for me in case of decimals and strict mode

Answer (score 7):

Just use an `UPDATE` query, it's way faster: `UPDATE table SET value=NULL WHERE value=0`.

Comment: `''` is **not** the same as `NULL`

Answer (score 3):

I used

> UPDATE userDetails set fame=0 where fame IS NULL;

if it to work. Since `=` did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using this method to clean individual columns but I would like to see if I can update an entire table doing the same method

UPDATE table SET value=NULL WHERE value=0.